# What Function in swift 5 that ‏ runs/exec an external swift script?

Tags: swift

I’m a former Python programmer, and I’m new to Swift

I want to know: is there a function that can exec/run another Swift file or external Swift script?

Just as an example. In Python I was using to `exec` another Python script:

```py
exec("print('Hello world')")
```

and the result:

> Hello world

That's it.

Comment: Show some python code, then I believe you are former and not current Python programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there is a library that can run external codes in swift Similar like your python Example, you can download the Library by github:

https://github.com/samuelmeuli/swift-exec

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this but I think so this article could maybe help you for what you are looking for.

Link: https://www.raywenderlich.com/25816315-using-swift-scripts-with-xcode